# Server Side Events on OpenShift times out (HTTP 504

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, openshift

I have a Spring Boot Application that provides a REST API. One of the endpoints is a stream (Server Side Events):

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/stream", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
      public Flux<ServerSentEvent<?>> stream() {
      ...
    }
```

Locally this works fine. However, when I deploy it on a OpenShift cluster I always get a HTTP Error 504. The other "normal" REST Endpoints work fine on OS.

Is there anything that I need to consider in the OpenShift configs? Networking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my heartbeat interval of 30 sec was too long. With 15 sec it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).